# Unity - Destroying one duplicated enemy leads to can't attack anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a "game" where you can attack enemies with a sword. All damages applies to only one enemy, even if i attack the other one. Also when I destroy the first I get this message

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'RectTransform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

How do I fix it?
Here's my code:

Attached to the enemy

```
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Transform healthBar;
    private Transform canvas;

    public float maxHealth = 100f;
    public float damage = 10f;
    float currentHealth;
    float barLength;

    private void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        GameObject gfx = gameObject.transform.Find("GFX").gameObject;
        canvas = gfx.transform.Find("Health Bar");
        GameObject canv = canvas.gameObject;
        healthBar = canv.transform.Find("Green Bar");

        barLength = canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width * canvas.localScale.x;
    }

    public void GetStruck()
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        if (currentHealth < 0) currentHealth = 0;

        healthBar.localScale = new Vector3(currentHealth / maxHealth, 1f, 1f);

        Vector3 p = healthBar.position;
        p -= damage / (maxHealth * 2) * barLength * transform.right * -1;
        healthBar.position = p;

        if(currentHealth == 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

And the sword attack

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwordAttack : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator animator;
    private EnemyHealth enemyHealth;

    private bool isAttacking;

    private void Start()
    {
        enemyHealth = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isAttacking = true;
            animator.Play("swordSwing", -1, 0f);
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1)
        {
            isAttacking = false;
        }

        animator.SetBool("isAttacking", isAttacking);

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(isAttacking && other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            enemyHealth.GetStruck();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy")` Your sword found one enemy, destroyed it, and tried to attack it again.

Comment: It looks like the GFX or Healthbar or canvas is shared with some enemies and this cause this Nullreference

Comment: The error message sounds quite self-explanatory to me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void Start()
    {
        enemyHealth = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
    }
```

This is your mistake. You are only getting 1 enemy's health at your start method and you are always decreasing from that enemy's health. Instead you can get the hitted enemy's health in your `OnTriggerEnter` method and apply damage to that enemy.

Comment: Solved thank you! I also changed `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy")` to `other`

Comment: Yeah it should be something like other.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>(); Also if i helped could you please give my answer a point and mark it as answer please.